# OAuth nonce in java code

Tags: twitter

How to write a code to generate `oauth nonce` for `twitter api`.
Nonce is 15 character in length for twitter

Suggest examples/links/code?

Answer (score 4):

```
import java.security.SecureRandom;

public static String nonceGenerator(){
    SecureRandom secureRandom = new SecureRandom();
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
        stringBuilder.append(secureRandom.nextInt(10));
    }
    String randomNumber = stringBuilder.toString();
    return randomNumber;
}
```

Check out my post for more information:
https://www.pythonorjava.com/single-post/2017/03/07/Secure-Random-Number-Generator-nonce